# angular - index.html recognize only functions defined in the default route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have wired problem in angular.
in my index.html I have nav bar with ng-click="go('')" for each tab.

'go' is function which defined in each of my controllers.

```
var sheepApp= angular.module('sheepApp', [
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngRoute',
    'firebase'
]);

sheepApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
      }).
      when('/vision', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/vision.html',
        controller: 'visionCtrl'
      }).
      when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
        controller: 'aboutCtrl'
      }).
      when('/gallery', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/gallery.html',
        controller: 'galleryCtrl'
      }).
      when('/videos', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/videos.html',
        controller: 'videosCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
      });
  }]);
```

the problem is that the 'go' function (and all others) only recognized if I'm now in the route defined as 'otherwise' (In my case -'home')

Why it can happen?

thanks

**EDIT**

all my conntollers defined in ctrls.js

example of one of the ctrls:

```
sheepApp.controller('joinUsCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope','$location',
    function ($scope, $rootScope,$location) {
        $rootScope.go = function ( path ) {
            $location.path( path );
        };

        $rootScope.isActive = function(tabName){
                return $location.path() == tabName;
        };

        $scope.he = he;
}]);
```

Comment: You need to show the controller or something where your go function is defined. This is not enough information.

Comment: did you included the other controllers files at the index?

Comment: Like i see you are using angular route, i suppose you have a **ngview** in the index.html, and the controller scope of the controller only works inside that ngview (the template in route), if you have the **go()** function outside the ngview, then never gonna works. Try a parent controller before the ngview with the function

Comment: @JesúsQuintana - so I don't undestand why it is work when I am in route 'home' (which defines as my oterwise option )

Comment: I edit my question with more data

Comment: If each controller definition injects its own definition for the `$rootScope.go` method, only the last one will actually work. In this case, it's the `otherwise` route.

Comment: @AustinMullins it's not relevant. If I open my app in route named 'vision', then 'go' function should be defined.

Comment: you should call `ng-click="go('/home')"` `/`is important to use routing..I assumed you didn't enable html5mode

Comment: no, the function is ok. it's not called at all. and as I wrote, when I'm in 'home' route - this function work great and continue to work good even when I'm in other pages. The problem is when I start my app not in the 'home' route

Answer (score 0):

This is a example of a working method go in $rootScope.
Check your console of chrome if throw an error then the controller is not added this line throw me a error  *$scope.he = he;* and the go function not changes. (Is based on your example with a littles changes).

```js
var sheepApp= angular.module('sheepApp', [
    'ngRoute'
]);

sheepApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/home', {
        template: '<div>{{controller.name}}</div>',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
      }).
      when('/vision', {
        template: '<div>{{controller.name}}</div>',
        controller: 'visionCtrl'
      }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
      });
  }]);


sheepApp.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope','$location',
    function ($scope, $rootScope,$location) {
        $rootScope.go = function ( path ) {
            alert("works in home");
        };
      
      $rootScope.asd = {asd:"asd"};

        $rootScope.isActive = function(tabName){
                return $location.path() == tabName;
        };
      $scope.controller={name:'home'}
}]).controller('visionCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope','$location',
    function ($scope, $rootScope,$location) {
        $rootScope.go = function ( path ) {
            alert("works in vision");
        };
      
      $rootScope.asd = {asd:"asd"};

        $rootScope.isActive = function(tabName){
                return $location.path() == tabName;
        };
      $scope.controller={name:'vision'}
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-route.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sheepApp">
  <button ng-click="go()">RootScope function</button>
  <a href="#/vision" > vision</a>
  <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
```